# Change default font size setting used in Visio 2010

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2010

How do you change the default font size used in Visio 2010?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The best I've been able to do is edit a master shape.

1. Right-click the stencil that contains the shape(s) you want to edit, click *Save As* and give the stencil a useful name.
2. Now the stencil is editable, woohoo! Right-click the shape whose defaults you want to change, select *Edit master → Edit Master Shape* and edit away.
3. When you're done, close the window (not Visio!) and make sure to save the changes.

Yes, this sucks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really edit the default text size, but if you have shapes under your "favorites" or a custom stencil, you can edit those. Those are the only things you can change.